# Spark time series Filter and GroupBy [Array Fields]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, group-by, time-series

I would like to solve the following problem involving time series data. 
My Dataset looks like this :

```
productId |websiteID | price | D |M |Y
A         |80        | 50,6  |2  |4 |2016
A         |80        | 51,3  |3  |4 |2016
A         |789       | 49,6  |2  |4 |2016
B         |90        | 115,3 |12 |2 |2017
B         |90        | 113,2 |11 |2 |2017
B         |250       | 119,6 |12 |2 |2017
B         |250       | 110,3 |11 |2 |2017
C         |789       | 80,6  |5  |6 |2015
C         |789       | 80,6  |6  |6 |2015
A         |789       | 52,6  |2  |4 |2016
```

Each product is sold by several sites and I have the price per day.
First, I want to create a data frame where I group all the prices by product and website in the form of time series. how to create a List or Array attribute in spark ?

I want this :

```
productId |websiteID | price time series 
A         |80          | [ 50.6,51,3] 
A         |789         | [49.9,52.56]
B         |90          | [115.3,113.6]
B         |250         | [119.6,110.3]
C         |789         | [80.6,80.6 ]
```

Once the data frame is created as above, I want to calculate the encliean distance between the time series of each site. My final dataframe should look like this one, the key is composed of the prodcut Id and set tow website Id, and an float filed where I can store the computed value distance.

```
Key               |euclidean distance  
(A,set(80,789))   |1.8867  
(B,set(90,250)    |5.4203
```

Comment: do you know how to calculate euclidean distance?

Comment: Yes this is not the problem. we can take any distance, thanks

Comment: if a and b are two vector of the same size, I calculate the distance like that:            
   `Math.sqrt(a zip b map( x=> Math.pow( x._1-x._2,2)) sum )`

Comment: I can help you get the midlle dataframe only

Comment: Yes it's great thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given input `dataframe` as

```
+---------+---------+-----+---+---+----+
|productId|websiteID|price|D  |M  |Y   |
+---------+---------+-----+---+---+----+
|A        |80       |50,6 |2  |4  |2016|
|A        |80       |51,3 |3  |4  |2016|
|A        |789      |49,6 |2  |4  |2016|
|B        |90       |115,3|12 |2  |2017|
|B        |90       |113,2|11 |2  |2017|
|B        |250      |119,6|12 |2  |2017|
|B        |250      |110,3|11 |2  |2017|
|C        |789      |80,6 |5  |6  |2015|
|C        |789      |80,6 |6  |6  |2015|
|A        |789      |52,6 |2  |4  |2016|
+---------+---------+-----+---+---+----+
```

You can get the middle `dataframe` you desire using `collect_list` aggregate function

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.orderBy("D","M","Y").groupBy("productId","websiteID").agg(collect_list("price").as("price time series"))
```

you should have

```
+---------+---------+-----------------+
|productId|websiteID|price time series|
+---------+---------+-----------------+
|B        |250      |[119,6, 110,3]   |
|B        |90       |[115,3, 113,2]   |
|A        |789      |[49,6, 52,6]     |
|C        |789      |[80,6, 80,6]     |
|A        |80       |[50,6, 51,3]     |
+---------+---------+-----------------+
```

now rest of the steps is to calculate `euclidean distance`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works fine, but how do you take into account the time values (D,M, Y), the price time series  will have to be sorted according to the  date

Comment: i have this  Exception:  org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: undefined function collect_list;   i used spark 1.6.2

Comment: collect_list is defined for spark 1.6.2 https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#collect_list(org.apache.spark.sql.Column) if collect_list is not working you can try collect_set both act the same